# Mainframe batch job - return code RC 8 from IEBCOPY

Tags: mainframe, jcl

```
 //VENKATBK JOB (3322332),'KRISHNA',TIME=(1,0),      
 // CLASS=A,NOTIFY=VENKATB,MSGLEVEL=(1,1),PRTY=1     
 //STEP2 EXEC PGM=IEBCOPY                            
 //SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                              
 //SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                              
 //SYSDUMP  DD SYSOUT=*                              
 //SYSUT1   DD DSN=VENKATB.KK.INPUT.COPY,DISP=SHR    
 //SYSUT2   DD DISP=SHR,DSN=VENKATB.KK.INPUT.COPY1   
 //SYSIN    DD *                                     
   COPY INDD=SYSUT1,                                 
        OUTDD=SYSUT2                                 
 /*
```

THE MESSEGE FROM THE SPOOL IS..,
i have got  return code maxcc=8.
i have wrote this program in different types by modifications still I am getting this maxcc=8 return code.
I don't know where did made a mistake. please help.

```
IEB1135I IEBCOPY  FMID HDZ1A10  SERVICE LEVEL NONE     DATED 20080414 DFP  
IEB1035I VENKATBK  STEP2    06:40:28 SUN 25 DEC 2022 PARM=''               
  COPY INDD=SYSUT1,                                                        
IEB107I INVALID CONTINUATION                                               
IEB118I CONTROL STATEMENT ERROR                                            
       OUTDD=SYSUT2                                                        
IEB115I END OF FILE ON SYSIN                                               
IEB151I JOB HAS TERMINATED WITH ERROR(S)                                   
IEB147I END OF JOB - 8 WAS HIGHEST SEVERITY CODE
```

Answer (score 3):

z/OS DFSMSdfp Utilities are a very old beast, and so is their syntax. Have a look at [Continuing utility control statements](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=statements-continuing-utility-control) in manual *z/OS DFSMSdfp Utilities*, chapter *Introduction*, topic *Control*:

> Utility control statements are contained in columns 1 through 71. A statement that exceeds 71 characters must be continued on one or more additional records. A nonblank character must be placed in column 72 to indicate continuation.

The important part in your case is: **A nonblank character must be placed in column 72 to indicate continuation.**

```
=COLS> ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8
000011 //SYSIN    DD *                                                                 
000012   COPY INDD=SYSUT1,                                                    *        
000013        OUTDD=SYSUT2                                                             
000014 /*
```